# Strange "undefined method" error in Ruby on Rails app after switching to Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Here's `prompt.rb`:

```
class Prompt < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :teacherUrl, :studentUrl, :image, :text;

  validates :title, :length => { :minimum => 5 };

  has_attached_file :image ;

  def initialize(params = nil)
    super(params)
    after_initialize
  end

  def after_initialize()
    self.teacherUrl = 'T' + (0...4).map{65.+(rand(26)).chr}.join ;
    self.studentUrl = 'S' + (0...4).map{65.+(rand(26)).chr}.join ;
  end
end
```

When I create a new Prompt from prompt_controller.rb (from the default 'new' method) I get:

```
undefined method `teacherUrl=' for #<Prompt:0x007fe3ac68adc0>
```

with the application trace

```
app/models/prompt.rb:14:in `after_initialize'
app/models/prompt.rb:10:in `initialize'
app/controllers/prompts_controller.rb:43:in `new'
app/controllers/prompts_controller.rb:43:in `new'
```

This was working perfectly with sqlite.  I've just switched my databases to Postgres and now this error is rising... it seems like it couldn't be related, but that's all that's changed (I can go back a revision and it works perfectly again).

What's the problem?  Isn't teacherUrl defined with attr_accessible?

Comment: Did you migrate your database correctly? What shows for the `prompts` table in `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: Aha, teacherUrl and studentUrl are missing... and yet `rake db:migrate` shows everything up to date (and I've restarted the server).  Thanks for the comment - I'll keep investigating

Comment: You were absolutely right, @RyanBigg - thanks!

Comment: You know you're going to have to double quote those two URL columns any time they appear in an SQL snippet, right? So you can't `where('teacherUrl like ?', ...)`, you have to `where('"teacherUrl" like ?', ...)` instead. You're better off using lower case column names with underscores to separate words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `rake db:migrate`. And possibly `rake db:create` (first).

Comment: This was essentially right, though the actual solution was more complicated because I screwed something up.  I reverted a migration which I thought only removed one field and it actually removed teacherUrl and studentUrl too.  So, I had to `rails g migration` those fields back on and then `db:migrate`.  Thanks!